# Can I develop android apps on Android tablet?

Tags: android, tablet

I have a Android tablet.  Can I develop apps which can work on Android phones using Android tablet?

Specs:
Tablet: Android HP Slate
Android version: 4.1

Comment: Maybe controlling a real computer from a desktop sharing app.

Comment: Thanks for your minuses Android geniuses .  You are the best. Humble NoChinDeluxe. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you only need to program an Android app once. It can be deployed to either a tablet or a handset in most cases. One thing to note about creating apps that work on both tablets and handsets is that you may need to design custom layouts for each, so that your app UI supports various screen densities.

See the Android docs for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you very much. The Android geniuses gave me two minuses.  But you gave me the answer. Thank you.